# Is there a way to reduce the vertical margin of equations from the above paragraph

Tags: math-mode, spacing, overleaf

I am using overleaf and these packages which may be relevant:

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

I am using `\begin{equation*}` and `\begin{align*}` to input math equations between text paragraphs but, for some unknown (to me) reason, LaTeX leaves what seems to be like two horizontal lines of spacing between a paragraph and the equation after it instead of just one like it does with the paragraph below.

I can even it out by adding space below but still it would be inconsistent with the spacing from using `$$ <equation> $$` which is normal (yet feels also slightly imbalanced).

Why is this happening when I have not really touched any "settings" from the package? How can I fix it?

Edit: Here is a sample input that showcases my problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[top=2.0cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, bottom=2.0cm]{geometry}

\allowdisplaybreaks


\begin{document}


\section*{Example}

This is a paragraph where I talk about what I do in the next equation blah blah blah blah blah blah, blah blah blah. Look at all the space below:

\begin{align*}
    E &= M C\times C\\
    E &= M C^2
\end{align*}

Look at the space above now. It's much lesser than the space above the equation.

Of course I could do this:

\begin{align*}
    E &= M C\times C\\
    E &= M C^2\\    % added a "\\"
\end{align*}

and now it looks balanced but it's still too much space for me. Can I reduce the margins between paragraph and equation?

\end{document}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: it is hard to tell what you have done as you have neither shown your input nor your output but make sure you never have a blank line in the source before displayed math environments. (`$$` is not latex syntax so shouldn't be used, it is lower level primitive tex syntax)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added an input that showcases the problem. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: as I guessed, the input is in error: you should never have a blank line before `align*` It generates a spurious white paragraph before the display

Comment: Oh, so I just stick \begin{align} to the text paragraph? Can't believe it was this.. it's supposed to be "write what you mean"... Thanks for your help!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved after the comments.